# Sending HTTP Request, Printing Data Before Next Interval

Tags: python, api, python-requests

My script send requests every 45 sec to API endpoint to get latest "Post Title", if there is a new one it prints on my console. Let's say script send request at 6:00:00 PM then next request will be 6:00:45 PM, if website post a new "Title" at 6:00:15 PM it doesn't print until next check which is 6:00:45 PM.. How do i modify script to print this new "Title" immediately rather waiting for next request until 6:00:45 PM.

Python script:

```
import requests
import time

url = 'https://example.com/api'
headers = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"}

previous_titles = []

def fetch_titles():
    global previous_titles
    while True:
        resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        data = resp.json()
    
        for title in data['latest']['posts']:
            if title['title'] not in previous_titles:
                current_time = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
                print(f"[{current_time}] {title['title']}")
                previous_titles.append(title['title'])
    
        time.sleep(45)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    fetch_titles()
```

I can set interval to check every 6 seconds and print new ones but i don't want to make to many requests to website.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this with POST requests if you can't ping the site more than once every 6 seconds. There is no way to transfer data from the server to the client without a request with this model. If you're the one architecting the backend, I would suggest looking into websockets or server side events. If you're not architecting the backend, there might already be an implementation of one or the other. What is the service that you're trying to ping?

Comment: This is GET requests not POST requests and script i already sent is working without any errors and it's printing new titles if there is a new one.

Api endpoint:
https://www.theblock.co/api/pagesPlus/data/latest/1?hid=undefined